# Creating a hierarical tree and retuning as xml using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a following table.

```
CategoryId        Category_name        ParentId
1                 Products                0
2                 Property                0
3                 Electronics             1
4                 Computer                3
5                 Camera                  3
6                 Books                   1
```

How can I return a hierarchical xml from this, using a SQL Server CTE ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you try this, you can achieve some degree of what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (CategoryID INT, CatName VARCHAR(50), ParentID INT)

INSERT INTO @test
VALUES(1, 'Products', 0), (2, 'Property', 0), (3, 'Electronics', 1),
(4, 'Computer', 3), (5, 'Camera', 3), (6, 'Books', 1),
(7, 'Beach-front villa', 2), (8, 'DVD', 1)

;WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    -- anchor
    SELECT CategoryID, CatName, ParentID, 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM @test
    WHERE ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    -- recurse
    SELECT t.CategoryID, t.CatName, t.ParentID, h.Level + 1 AS 'Level'
    FROM Hierarchy h 
    INNER JOIN @test t ON t.ParentID = h.CategoryID
)
SELECT 
    h.CategoryID AS '@ID', h.CatName,
    (SELECT 
        h2.CategoryID AS '@ID', h2.CatName AS '@Name',
        (SELECT 
            h3.CategoryID AS '@ID', h3.CatName AS '@Name'
         FROM Hierarchy h3
         WHERE h3.ParentID = h2.CategoryID
         FOR XML PATH('BottomLevelItem'), TYPE) AS 'SubItems'
     FROM Hierarchy h2
     WHERE h2.ParentID = h.CategoryID
     FOR XML PATH('Item'), TYPE) AS 'Items'
FROM Hierarchy h
WHERE h.Level = 1
FOR XML PATH('TopLevelItem'), ROOT('AllItems')
```

This gives you a result something like this:

```
<AllItems>
  <TopLevelItem ID="1">
    <CatName>Products</CatName>
    <Items>
      <Item ID="3" Name="Electronics">
        <SubItems>
          <BottomLevelItem ID="4" Name="Computer" />
          <BottomLevelItem ID="5" Name="Camera" />
        </SubItems>
      </Item>
      <Item ID="6" Name="Books" />
      <Item ID="8" Name="DVD" />
    </Items>
  </TopLevelItem>
  <TopLevelItem ID="2">
    <CatName>Property</CatName>
    <Items>
      <Item ID="7" Name="Beach-front villa" />
    </Items>
  </TopLevelItem>
</AllItems>
```

With the `FOR XML PATH()` syntax in SQL Server 2005 and up, you can achieve a lot of flexibility - you can define certain columns to show up as attributes on the XML nodes, and other can be used as XML elements.

What I haven't found a solution for as of yet is having an infinitely deep nesting of the various entries - here in my example, you have three levels deep - no more, no less. You can make that four or five levels - but I don't know how you could extend that to *any depth* of nesting....

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same for locations for our application and I did it by iterating through elements. I wonder if there is an easy way.